# Computing (prefix, repetition_count, suffix) slices of an infinitely-repeated string

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Let us repeat a sequence such as `abcd` infinitely, yielding the following array:

```
abcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcd (...)
```

This is the problem: Given two indexes l and r (l < r), return the sub-array starting at index l and ending at r.

But since the array is circular, representing its partition with a regular array would be wasting memory, instead two sub-arrays (a prefix and a suffix) of the original sequence (here `abcd`) and a number signifying the number of full repeats of the sequence in the partition would be enough to define the partition.

Here's an example:

```
l = 5
r = 18

abcdab|cd.abcdabcd.abc|dabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcdabcd (...)

prefix = "cd"
sufix = "abc"
repeats = 2
```

Of course, not every case fits this scheme so perfectly like the one above. Sometimes the prefix will be empty, sometimes the suffix, sometimes there won't be any repeats of the whole sequence, and so on. In fact there's one special case, when the partition fits wholly within one repeat of the sequence (`abcda|bc|dabcdabcd(...)`), that can't be represent in this way at all and should be represented by just one string.

And that's not the only thing making this problem hellish. Since it's bound to include modular arithmetic, it hides many off-by-one errors to be made. Thus I'm setting no restrictions regarding inclusive or exclusive bounds and 0-indexed and 1-indexed. You may use whatever makes the math simplest. Any algorithm is easily adapted to work for any of these settings by simply adding or subtracting 1 from some arguments.

Bonus points if you make it work with negative indexes.

As far as I'm concerned this is language agnostic. Just pseudocode or even plain math equations for getting some critical values would be enough.

Comment: What do you intend to do with the result?  More specifically, why can't you just use `l` and `r` directly in whatever output processing you intend to do?

Comment: Would it be simpler to note that in your example, the part that you have selected is also "cdab" * 3 + "c"?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth For operations on the partition that approach would be O(length of partition) but this approach is O(length of sequence), which in most cases is much faster. My particular context is competitive programming problems.

Comment: @moreON Interesting. I think keeping the format of the partition constant would lend itself better to operations upon it. But I your approach would be fast, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modulo operator is key here. Reading index `a` from the repeated string will read at index `a % len(s)` in the un-repeated string. So e.g. the slice `s[:end % len(s)]` is the suffix.

In a language like python, where division rounds towards negative infinity instead of towards zero (where `-1 % 3 == 2` and `-1 // 3 == -3` instead of `-1 % 3 == -1` and `-1 / 3 == 0`), code written for the non-negative index case will automatically apply to the negative index case.

There are two tricky corner cases to watch for in this problem:

1. The slice might fall entirely within the same repetition of the string. The prefix/rep-count/suffix convention makes no sense in that case. Code that doesn't check for this case will put bad extra characters into the prefix and suffix, and return a negative repetition count.

   `slice_cyclic_string('abcd', 1, 3)` shouldn't return `('bcd', -1, 'abc')`, it should fall back to a raw string result.
2. Slices might land on repetition boundaries. Naive code might put a full repetition into the prefix or suffix, instead of into the repetition count.

   `slice_cyclic_string('abcd', 0, 8)` should return `('', 2, '')`, not `('abcd', 1, '')` or `('', 1, 'abcd')` or `('abcd', 0, 'abcd')`

As with most code involving modulo, dealing with tricky boundary cases is done by shifting-then-unshifting by 1 before and after the modulo operator in random places.

Here's python code that does what you want, **except it follows the python convention of the `end` index being exclusive and indices being zero-based**. `slice_cyclic_string("abcd", 5, 18)` returns `('bcd', 2, 'ab')`:

```
def slice_cyclic_string(repeated_string, start, end):
  n = len(repeated_string)

  if start > end:
      raise ValueError("start > end")
  if start // n == end // n:
      # The slice lies entirely within one repetition.
      return repeated_string[start % n : end % n]

  prefix = repeated_string[(start-1) % n + 1:]
  suffix = repeated_string[:end % n]
  reps = (end - start - len(prefix) - len(suffix)) // n

  return prefix, reps, suffix
```

Comment: "As with most code involving modulo, dealing with tricky boundary cases is done by shifting-then-unshifting by 1 before and after the modulo operator in random places." - Haha, that is exactly my experience with the modulo, especially this problem. Figuring out where the +1s and -1s go in the middle of a timed competition is not exactly easy. Thank you so much for this solution, it works perfectly! Now I just have to memorize it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that we start indexing with 0 and that sub-array stars with `l+1` as in Your example. And instead of `prefix` and `sufix` i would like to use `s` and `f` which are indexes of first character of your prefix and last character of your sufix in repeated pattern. `s=2` and `f=2` in Your example. I also assume that `n` is length of repeated pattern.

```
s = (l + 1) mod n 
f = r mod n
repeats = (r-l -(n-s) -(n-f+1))/n
```

Comment: According to some quick tests, this doesn't work with many edge cases. Try things like `abcd|abcdabcdab|cd`, or `abcd|abcdabcd|abcd`, or `a|bc|d`. Also, I apologize for suggesting the first element should be l+1, that was just me miscounting in the example.